Call withCredentials and passing different credential ids
The goal of the job is to call a function that runs commands on certain machines. Since the machines will be in difference clouds, subscriptions, etc we have different credentials to be able to access. I have tried calling the defined function I have, and it pass it a variable to withCredentials() but I always get errors.
I have tried several things such as adding @NONCPS on top of the function definition. I have tried to have the definition outside of the pipeline scope. I have tried with variable combinations of $variable, ${variable} but they all yield the same similar error with serialization.
I also tried what was suggested here: https://community.jenkins.io/t/using-withcredentials-in-freestyle-groovy-script/3051 but got the same error.
The sample script is bellow:
    def server_inventory='''[
      {
        "agentName": "agent01",
        "machineName": "dev-agent01",
        "instanceId": "i-xxxxx",
        "cloud": "aws",
        "accountName": "DevQa",
        "accountId": xxxxxxxx,
        "directoryId": "",
        "resourceGoup": "",
        "region": "us-east-1",
        "credential": "awsDevQA"
      },
      {
        "agentName": "agent20",
        "machineName": "pp-agent20",
        "instanceId": "",
        "cloud": "azure",
        "accountName": "pp",
        "accountId": xxxxxxxx,
        "directoryId": "xxxxxx",
        "resourceGoup": "rg-pp",
        "region": "eastus",
        "credential": "azPP"
      },
      .
      .
      .
      .
    '''
    
    def gl_confData = readJSON(text: server_inventory)
    
     stages{
        stage('agent commands'){
          steps{
            script{
              def startAzureVm = {vmName, resourceGroup, jenkinsCred, tenantId ->
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: jenkinsCred, passwordVariable: 'AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET', usernameVariable: 'AZURE_CLIENT_ID')]){
                  sh script: 'az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $tenantId'
                  Sh '<run other commands'>
              }
    
              def getVmDetails = {agentName ->
                return gl_confData.find{it.agentName == agentName}
              }
    
              def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("${JOB_NAME}")
              def agentParam = job.getProperty(hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty.class).getParameterDefinition('Agent')
              def agentChoices = agentParam.getChoices()
              
                agentChoices.each{ str ->
                  def agent = getVmDetails(str)
                  if(agent){
                    if(agent.cloud == 'azure'){
                      startAzureVm(agent.machineName, agent.resourceGoup, agent.credential, agent.directoryId)
                    }
                  }
                }
              }    
            }
          }
        }
    }

The error is:
> an exception which occurred:  in field
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.withscript.WithScriptScript.script
>   in object
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.agent.impl.LabelScript@715df3b8
>   in field groovy.lang.Closure.delegate   in object
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@4f26f1b8   in field
> groovy.lang.Closure.delegate  in object
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@36918bf9   in field
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures    in object
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@7511cc00    in object
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@7511cc00 Also:  
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId:
> 085e099e-d54d-4c29-ad88-7805002639d6 Caused:
> java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.model.Hudson     at
> PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:278)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(LinkedHashMap.java:334)
>   at java.base/java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1497)   at
> PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:157)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:231)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1128)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-cps//com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.SerializableScript.writeObject(SerializableScript.java:26)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:157)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:231)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1128)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1119)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
>   at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1944)
>   at java.base/java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1497)   at
> PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:157)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:231)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1128)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1182)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:1140)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:271)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:116)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$1(RiverWriter.java:147)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> script-security//org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:331)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-support//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:146)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:580)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:557)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:540)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:464)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:331)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:295)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$wrap$4(CpsVmExecutorService.java:140)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
> hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
>   at
> jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>   at
> jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
>   at
> jenkins.util.ErrorLoggingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(ErrorLoggingExecutorService.java:51)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
>   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
>   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:53)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$1.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:136)
>   at
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:275)
>   at PluginClassLoader for
> workflow-cps//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService.lambda$categoryThreadFactory$0(CpsVmExecutorService.java:50)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)


The log tells you that some object is not serializable and then mentions workflow-support a lot. If you look at your code this line would produce a non serializable variable:
              def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("${JOB_NAME}")

Maybe sacrifice readability a bit and chain the following calls to get something that can be serialized, like a list of strings:
def agentChoices = Jenkins.het().getItemByFullName("${JOB_NAME}")
  .getProperty(hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty.class)
  .getParameterDefinition('Agent')
  .getChoices()

There might be other issues with your code, hard to tell without running it.

that didn't work, but you led me to the right path. I ended up just removing that part of the code and will just have a text field as the variable and no choices. It is not as pretty but it works, I am not well versed with Java so the serialization thing threw me off. Thank you so much for your help.
Also btw how did you know that part was the issue with serialization?

It's a well known Jenkins gotcha.
